# C Programming : Hash Key (uint32) generation ( Inputs : one uint32 and one uint64 to generate unique key)

Tags: c

For my hash table, I need to generate one unique key of type uint32 from the inputs : one uint32 and one uint64 variables. Can you please help me out to generate a unique key of type uint32.

Output : one uint32 unique value.

Inputs : One uint32 and one uint64

Can you please help me with the Logic

Comment: sorry i was closed your question.if you add any of your try then i will reopen it.

Comment: Can you please help me out in generating a unique value with the two inputs a mentioned above.

Comment: If your input is one uint32 and one uint64, and your output is one uint32, then you have 96 bits of input and 32 bits of output, and (unless there is something you haven't told us) you _can't_ generate a unique output for each input. But hashing to a _unique_ hash value is not how hashing works. You will have collisions if your input has more bits than your generated hash value, and that is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: You need to show that you tried something; if you search Google for "hash function algorithm" you'll find a lot of hits. And hash values don't need to be unique - read more about how hash tables work.

Comment: If I have two variables 'uint32 a' and 'uint64 b' then with these two variables 'a' and 'b' I need one unique number of type 'uint32' such that, the unique number I need to used for my hash table.

Comment: @Sailesh [Read this once before asking Question On SO, then you should not ask like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are implementing a hash function for a hash table.
Basically You can fold the uint64_t with an xor and xor the result with the uint32_t.

```
uint32_t hash( uint32_t a , uint64_t b ) {
  return a ^   (b >> 32 )   ^ b;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will it be unique for different values of a and b? Just thought of confirming.

Comment: No it can't be unique but it somehow preserves the distribution of input . You cannot store 96 bits of information into 32bits of information.

Comment: I would personally shift a little more. If a and b are equal, this hash function will always be zero. That might not be a problem, but a==b seems like a thing that could happen more than randomly, so unless I knew something more about the input I would take that into consideration.

Comment: @Thomas, I agree with you.